# Android studio crash with firebase database on hello world example

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

        myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

and in build.gradle have this problem:

[image]

The problem is: 
Every time I run this application he crashes.
And I don't know why this is happening, I need help with this problem.

Logcat:

[image]

Comment: Please go to this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup to setup firebase in your app, it seems you miss a lot of steps.

Comment: this is not a crash log, its a warning. Put screenshot of your logcat for more details

Comment: I've made an update with logcat

Comment: FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this); this can solve your problem. Try as mention in answer below by @MeosCoder

Comment: copy and paste the error in the logcat, and stop sending photos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need implement this:
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'`

**Update**

Add `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);` in your application class.

Create class extends `Application`

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    }
}
```

In Android Manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication">
</application>
```

Comment: the warning is no longer available, but the application crashes

Comment: Add `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);` in your application class.
Or before getInstance firebase.